# Where can I find examples of how to use Netflix/nebula gradle-stash-plugin?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, bitbucket-server

I have a requirement to automate Atlassian stash related tasks within my Gradle builds.

I have tracked down the Netflix/nebula gradle-stash-plugin which looks as though it will perform all the work I require.

My issue is I cannot find any examples of how to use it?

Is there a "Cookbook" or examples/tutorials?